# An API fetcher class - afraid of overengineering class

Tags: java, beginner

I'd like to ask you for a code review of this class. I'm quite new to Java and I'm afraid I have way overengineered this class. It's goal is only to fetch a specified data from given API, whose link is stored in config.properties.

I would be grateful for both implementation details critique and design ones too.

```
package org.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


public class APIDataFetcher {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(APIDataFetcher.class);
    private static final Properties properties = new Properties();

    static {
        try (InputStream inputStream = APIDataFetcher.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                properties.load(inputStream);
            } else {
                logger.info("config.properties file not found in resources.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error loading configuration file.", e);
        }
    }

    public static void saveData(String fileName, JsonNode jsonNode) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

            String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
            Path filePath = Paths.get(fileName);
            Files.write(filePath, jsonString.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error occurred while writing JSON to file: " + fileName, e);
        }
    }

    public static JsonNode getJSONString() {
        try {
            return parseJSON(fetchAllData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error occurred while fetching or parsing data", e);
            return null;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static JsonNode parseJSON(String jsonString) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);
    }

    private static String fetchAllData() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader reader = getReader()) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                responseBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    }

    private static BufferedReader getReader() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        String apiUrl = properties.getProperty("api.url");
        URI uri = new URI(apiUrl);
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            logger.error("Could not connect to the data source. HTTP Status Code: " + responseCode);
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not connect to the data source. HTTP Status Code: " + responseCode);
        }
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## simple things should be simple

```
1        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
2        try (BufferedReader reader = getReader()) {
3            String line;
4            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
5                responseBuilder.append(line);
6            }
7        }
8        return responseBuilder.toString();
```

I don't understand why this isn't a one-liner:

```
         return getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Less dramatically, `parseJSON()` also could be a one-liner.

## global vs local names

Your method names are all very nice and self-explanatory; keep it up.

Consider using brief names, maybe 2 characters or so, for local variables. Their meaning tends to be quite clear from context.

Some java code can develop a `Bond james = Bond()` quality to it,
which short names will soften a bit.

## coupling to config file

Consider offering a signature of `getReader(String apiUrl)`.
And then a one-liner `getReader()` can call it with that property
if you feel you need that.

As stated it relies on sort of a hidden global variable,
and it's not convenient for promotion to `public` re-use
nor even for being called by
[unit tests](https://junit.org/junit5).

The `getJSONString()` signature is rather cryptic in the same way.
It would benefit from taking an argument, to clarify what it's reading.

## javadoc

Your method names are good, and for `private` methods that suffices.
But your `public` methods would benefit from
at least a one-sentence /** javadoc */ description of their
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).
Caller wants to know: "What's the contract? What can I rely on?"